# Relationship of $L_1$ distance between CDFs and PDFs?

Tags: integration, inequality, probability-distributions

Let $F:(-\infty,\infty)\rightarrow[0,1]$ and $G:(-\infty,\infty)\rightarrow[0,1]$ two CDFs with PDFs $f$ and $g$, respectively. Is there a connection/inequality between:

$$d_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vert f(t) - g(t) \vert dt,$$
and
$$d_2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vert F(t) - G(t) \vert dt?$$
Assuming $d_2$ exists ($d_1$ is always finite).

Answer (score 2):

Well, $d_2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left | \int_{-\infty}^t f(s) ds - g(s) ds \right | dt \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^t |f(s)-g(s)| ds dt$. As a rule of thumb, the triangle inequality tends to be fairly tight, so this suggests that $d_2$ could be quite large even though $d_1$ is small, by accumulating some difference between the CDFs far to the left. For example, you could have $f(x)=\begin{cases} 0.1 & x \in [-M-1,-M] \\ 0.9 & x \in [0,1] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ and $g(x)=1_{[0,1]}(x)$, where $M>0$. Then $d_1=0.2$ but $d_2$ is at least $0.1M$.

On the flipside, there might be a nontrivial bound on $d_1$ in terms of $d_2$, I'm not sure about that. (At the same time, $d_2$ is kind of a weird object, because CDFs themselves are never in $L^1$, so you are measuring the $L^1$ distance between two non-$L^1$ objects.)